# Hiding multiple divs on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Working on a form where I need to hide or show divs based on user selections. I've managed to get the first div selector value to show the 2nd div, however the 3rd isn't showing up based on the 2nd div selector value. Just wrapping my head around Javascript & appreciate any assistance.

Here's the general HTML

```
<!-- Div 1 -->

  <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="div1">
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Choice 3</option>
  <option value='4'>Choice 4</option>

</select>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Div 2 -->

<div class="col-md-12" id="div2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="div2">Label for Div 2</label>

    <select class="form-control" id="div2">
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Choice 3</option>

</select>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Div 3 -->
  <div class="col-md-6" id="div3">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="div3">Div 3 label</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value">
 </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#div2').hide();

    $('#div1').change(function(){
        if($('#div1').val() > 2) {
            $('#div2').show('fast'); 
        } else {
            $('#div2').hide('scale'); 
        }
   }); 

    $('#div3').hide();

    $('#div2').change(function(){
        if($('#div2').val() > 2) {
            $('#div3).show('fast'); 
        } else {
            $('#div3').hide('scale'); 
        }
   }); 

  });

// end ready()

  </script>
```

Comment: id should be unique. That's where your probleme is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the divs and the selects with the same ID. It can't identify any value for the div "div2" as there is none.

Changing the HTML:

```
<!-- Div 1 -->

  <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="div1-selector">
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Choice 3</option>
  <option value='4'>Choice 4</option>

</select>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Div 2 -->

<div class="col-md-12" id="div2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="div2">Label for Div 2</label>

    <select class="form-control" id="div2-selector">
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>Choice 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Choice 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Choice 3</option>

</select>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Div 3 -->
  <div class="col-md-6" id="div3">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="div3">Div 3 label</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value">
 </div>
  </div>
```

And the jquery references will do.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ff8hxu93/

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `'` here `$('#div3).show('fast');` and you have `id`s that are the same. Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3whLyzqq/1/) .  Note the change to `id`s . You should also check out `$(this)` - I put an example of its usage in the second `change` listener